# How to extract two subfields "n" from my XML?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following XML:

```
<datafield tag="036F">
<subfield code="d">DVZ : Zeitung für Verkehr und Logistik</subfield>
<subfield code="p">Hamburg</subfield>
<subfield code="n">DVV-Media Group</subfield>
<subfield code="n">1947-</subfield>
</datafield>
```

I'm trying to extract and concatenate these two subfields "n" and separate them with comma.

That's my XSLT:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="$pica036F">
<xsl:variable name="codeN"> 

<xsl:value-of select="concat(./subfield[@code='n'],'')" /> 
    </xsl:variable> 
</xsl:for-each>
```

The problem is that only one "n" will be extracted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using XSLT 2.0, I would expect an error if you used `concat` here, saying "*Error: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of concat()*" because `concat` expects strings as parameters.

You should be using `string-join` here

```
<xsl:value-of select="string-join(subfield[@code='n'], ',')" />
```

If, on the other hand, are actually using an XSLT 1.0 processor, then you can use an `xsl:for-each` (as `string-join` won't be available)

```
<xsl:for-each select="subfield[@code='n']">
   <xsl:if test="position() > 1">,</xsl:if>
   <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Note that, if your XML was only ever going to have two matching sub-fields, you could use `concat` like so:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(subfield[@code='n'][1], ',', subfield[@code='n'][2])" />
```